# how to scrape data from that svg tag

Tags: java, selenium

why all the company list avg salary,avg exp,in lacs all data didnt scrape

```
driver.get("https://careernavigator.naukri.com/sales-executive-retail-careers-in-mahindra-and-mahindra-financial-services-15731");
String webtable = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/div[@class='wrapper']/div[@class='leftwrap fl']/div[@id='f1']/div[@id='rph1']/*[1]")).getText();
System.out.println(webtable);
```

i want result what it showing in table ,but i get result Mahindra and Mahindra Financia..4.8 2.4
1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6

Comment: what output you want, can you add in your question, it seems you want all the rows of the table in output, but u r getting only first row in output ?

Comment: i only getting first 3 row ..but i want all 25 row i consol @Amit Jain

Comment: plz @AmitJain plz help

Comment: You are trying to dump the entirety of the SVG. It's not going to get you what you want because it's not organized in any way. Likely what's happening is you are dumping it before it's done loading. Also, your locator is very brittle and WAY too complicated. All you need is the CSS selector, `#rph1 > svg`.

Comment: JeffC  i tried CSS selector #rph3 > svg > a > text>tspan....but this one showing 22 list...how to get one particular text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are opening url without login. 
I opened url after login and able to see full table, some thing like this. Then your xpath will work.

[image]

Comment: with login it open full table but my data is not showing correctly@Amit jain